# Convert BIM model (building) with 1000+ parts from HiPoly to LowPoly

Tags: modeling

I have imported a gigantic model of a building, and it has 1000's of sub-meshes. I need to convert this monster to a fairly low-poly thing. I don't want to have to select each mesh and decimate it. I'd be here all year. Is there something off the shelf that will take a model and low-poly each of its submeshes or better yet, "figure the whole thing out" and merge submeshes with each other? Or even better yet, all I want is all the outward-facing polygons. I don't care what's "inside" the building.

Comment: Hello :). This sounds like a job for the [Remesh Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html).

Comment: Can you weed out the unnecessary parts in the BIM software before export? In my experience, taking some time preparing the model for export in CAD-like softwares usually saves a lot of effort afterwards...

Comment: can't weed out the unnecessary parts. I already have. What is left is just unnecessarily complex wall and door and window data w/ way too many vertexes.

Comment: Have you tried importing it in IFC format via [BlenderBIM](https://blenderbim.org/)?